# Understanding timestamp- 1505143211567 (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following timestamp "1505143211567". By removing the last 3 numbers I can able to convert to normal human readable format. The DB is running from Oracle. I want to convert this timestamp to human readable. I tried something like below.

From sql I can write it by removing last 3 and

```
select from_unixtime(1505143211)
```

But in oracle its kind of different. And each time I dont want to remove the number and check manually.

**Need is : DB query.**

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you are getting seems to be an EPOC value, when using an online converter I got the following:

```
1505143211567 -> 2017-09-11 15:20:12
```

I'm no expert in Oracle, however there are a lot of resources out there in converting this to a human readable format, does the following help ?

```
select TO_CHAR( FROM_TZ( CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1/24/60/60/1000) * <column name> AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/London'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from <tablename>;
```

Where `column name` is your timestamp column, and `tablename` is obviously the table you are getting the column from. *source can be found [here](https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/2/158526.aspx)*.

You also have a few stackoverflow posts with the issue as well.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305135/oracle-convert-unix-epoch-time-to-date) might be a good one to follow.

Comment: I do prefer `1 / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`, so I don't have to figure out the precedence of the `/` operator.