# Converting a Unix time stamp using Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle

I am using SQL developer to run queries on a database and one of the tables shows a create date for each request added. The query pulls a unix time stamp back and I haven't had much luck on Google when searching for Oracle SQL Dev.

```
select ID, CREATED
from REQUESTS
where ID = 'bob'
order by create_date DESC;
```

Comment: And you tag SQL Server for what reason? And you did NOT tag Oracle for what reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle convert unix epoch time to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305135/oracle-convert-unix-epoch-time-to-date)

Comment: Chill bruh - Thanks ill check it out

Comment: What format is your Unix “time stamp”? Number of string? And what does it look like? As an aside, is the column in ORDER BY the same as in SELECT? It doesn’t look like it.

Comment: It would help to show example of these timestamp values, no?